# Searching SQL database for certain string and returning row id where that string exists

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Hi I am trying to check my database to see if a particular string exists in this case the column title and then I want to return the ID of that row so I can take all the information from that row and use it for some extra validation.

I have attempted this in my getAppointment ID method however I keep getting a cursor index error of -1. Once I am able to return the ID I plan to use it to retrieve the row and return an instance of the correct appointment. I'm very new to SQL and any helper would be appreciated.

```
public class MyDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "appointments.db";
public static final String TABLE_APPOINTMENTS = "appointments";
public static final String _ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_DAY = "day";
public static final String COLUMN_MONTH = "month";
public static final String COLUMN_YEAR = "year";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";
public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "details";


public MyDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_APPOINTMENTS
            + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_DAY + " INTEGER, " + COLUMN_MONTH + " INTEGER, " + COLUMN_YEAR + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_APPOINTMENTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public int getAppointmentID(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    int i=0;

    String selection = COLUMN_TITLE + " = ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{name};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_APPOINTMENTS, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.moveToNext())
            i = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return i;
}


public void addAppointment(Appointment app){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_DAY, app.get_day());
    values.put(COLUMN_MONTH, app.get_month());
    values.put(COLUMN_YEAR, app.get_year());
    values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, app.get_title()); // need to check that string being entered isn't already a unique entry
    values.put(COLUMN_TIME, app.get_time());
    values.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, app.get_details());
    db.insert(TABLE_APPOINTMENTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public Appointment getAppointment(int a){
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_APPOINTMENTS + " WHERE id 
 = " + Integer.toString(a);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Appointment app = new Appointment();

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
            app.set_day(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(1)));
            app.set_month(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(2)));
            app.set_year(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(3)));
            app.set_title(c.getString(4));
            app.set_time(c.getString(5));
            app.set_details(c.getString(6));
    }
    return app;
}    

}
```

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `getAppointmentID()` method like below:

```
public int getAppointmentID(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    int i=0;
    String[] projection = {_ID};
    String selection = COLUMN_TITLE + " = ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{name};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_APPOINTMENTS, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();                      
    }

    i = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return i;
}
```

Comment: That did it many thanks, would you mind explaining the changes you made please?  I would like to improve my knowledge around this area.

Comment: You were moving your cursor to `moveToNext()` though you had only one row as output. You were also putting `NULL` value in the output column. And you should always close the `db` after finishing your work or else you can face memory leak.

Comment: It's been pleasure.